# change variable when inputs changed in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-input

When numbers are entered in the price(Fiyat) fields in the picture, I want the place that says 0 TL to change. The place that says 0 TL should be the sum of the numbers step by step. How can i do that?

`<td><input (keypress)="keyPressNumbersWithDecimal($event)" type="text" id="price_{{i}}" name="price"/></td>`

`<td colspan="3" style="color: #f87575; text-align: right; ">{{totalPrice}} TL</td>`

Note : number of inputs is dynamic

[image]

Comment: are the total number of inputs dynamic in number? if they are static you could just use two way binding. Then your 0 TL would be something like <span>{{ prop1 + prop2 + prop3}} TL</span>

Comment: Number of inputs is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input (keypress)="keyPressNumbersWithDecimal($event)" type="text" id="price_{{i}}" name="price"/>
```

Try

```
<input [(ngModel)]="totalPrice" type="text" id="price_{{i}}" name="price"/>
```